# How do I change footnote in Beamer?

Tags: beamer, numbering, footnotes

I would like to change footnote sign letter to numbers in my Beamer presentation. How can I achive this?

Comment: I cannot test it now, but would `\def\thefootnote{\arabic{footnote}}` placed _just after_ `\begin{document}` help? **(There was a mistake, I edited it now!)**

Comment: Can you post a minimal example that shows the problem.  The default numbering for footnotes in Beamer is numeric, not alphabetic.

Answer (score 9):

Without a minimal working example, all I can do is to guess; the standard behaviour for footnotes in `beamer` is similar to the one in standard classes:  numeric in "regular" text, but alphabetic inside `minipage` or `columns` environments, as the following example shows:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\begin{columns}
\column{.6\textwidth}
Some text\footnote{a test footnote inside a \texttt{columns} or \texttt{minipage} environment.}
\stepcounter{footnote}
\end{columns}
Some text\footnote{a test regular footnote.}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

This is os because two different counters are in play: `footnote` for "regular text" footnotes and `mpfootnote` for footnotes inside `minipage` or `columns`. If you want the footnotes inside `columns` or `minipage` to be also numbered using arabic numerals you need to redefine the representation for the `mpfootnote` counter; you will also possibly need to step `footnote` to maintain syncronicity with regular footnotes; here's the above code with the mentioned modification:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\renewcommand\thempfootnote{\arabic{mpfootnote}}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\begin{columns}
\column{.6\textwidth}
Some text\footnote{a test footnote inside a \texttt{columns} or \texttt{minipage} environment.}
\stepcounter{footnote}
\end{columns}
Some text\footnote{a test regular footnote.}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]